# How does this code move the bird sprite in this sketch?

Tags: programming, c, sketch

I'm teaching this [sketch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hxxvueidqjoi09/flappyDuino.zip?dl=0) in my class. I understand most of the sketch and can see the class that makes the bird move, but I still don't quite understand how the code makes the sprite "move." I can also see what generates the Pipes but I don't how the code creates them or randomizes them.

Here is the code for both:

Bird

```
class Chym {

private:
  int frameCount;
  int x; 
  int y;
  int deltaIde;
  int delayFrame;

  int jumpCount; 
  int maxJumpCount;
  int moveSpeed;

  bool _isDead;
public: 
  void respawn() {
    x = 24; 
    y = 20;
    deltaIde = -1;
    moveSpeed = 1;
    jumpCount = 0;
    _isDead = false;
  }

  Chym() {
    frameCount = 0;
    delayFrame = 0;
    maxJumpCount = 20;
    respawn();
  }

  void render() {
    if (frameCount < ANIM_FRAME / 2) {
      display.drawBitmap(x, y, flappybird_frame_1, 16, 12, 1);      
    } 
    else {
      display.drawBitmap(x, y, flappybird_frame_2, 16, 12, 1);          
    }
  }

  void update() {
    delayFrame++;
    if (delayFrame == DELAY_FRAME) {
      y += deltaIde * moveSpeed;
      delayFrame = 0;
    }

    if (y > 35) {
      _isDead = true;
    }

    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount >= ANIM_FRAME) frameCount = 0;
  }

  bool isDead() {
    return _isDead;
  }

  void die() {
    _isDead = true;
  }

  void cancelJump() {
    jumpCount = 0;
    flyDown();
  }

  void flyUp() {
    if (jumpCount < maxJumpCount) {
      deltaIde = -1; 
      moveSpeed = 3;    
      jumpCount++;
    } 
    else {
      flyDown();
    }
  }

  void flyDown() {
    deltaIde = 1; 
    moveSpeed = 1;
  }

  int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  int getY() {
    return y;
  }

};
```

Pipe

```
class Bar {

private:
  int x; 
  int y;
  int delayFrame;
  int moveSpeed;
public:   
  Bar() {
    delayFrame = 0;
    x = 0; y = 24;
    moveSpeed = 2;
  }

  void setPos(int sx, int sy) {
    x = sx; y = sy;
  }

  void render() {
    display.drawBitmap(x, y - 30, bar_top, 8, 20, 1); 
    display.drawBitmap(x, y + 10, bar_bottom, 8, 20, 1); 
  }

  void update() {
    delayFrame++;
    if (delayFrame == DELAY_FRAME) {

      x -= moveSpeed;
      if (x < -10) x = 95;

      delayFrame = 0;
    }
  }

  int hitTest(int tx, int ty) {
    int hitX = ((tx >= x - 16) && (tx <= x))?1:0;
    int hitY = ((ty <= (y - 10)) || (ty + 12 >= y + 10))?1:0;
    if (hitX != 0) {
      return hitY;
    }
    return 0;
  }

};
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04cY78Y2d3g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code is what changes the sprite's y-value.

```
y += deltaIde * moveSpeed;
```

When you click the "jump" button or when the bird falls the y-value is changed to reflect either an upward movement or a downward movement. When your `render()` method is called the bird will either be drawn higher up on the y-axis (it's flying) or lower on the y-axis (it's falling).

As for the bars, if you watch closely in the video you can see that they aren't actually randomized.

**Compound Assignment Operators**

`+=` is the "plus assign" operator. It adds whatever is on the right side to the variable on the left side. Here is a table of other compound assignment operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators

```
int x = 5;
x += 2; // equals 7; equivalent to x = x + 2;
x = 5;
x = x + 2; // also equals 7; equivalent to x += 2;
```

Comment: What does the += mean?

Comment: @GabeRuiz, it was said in the same post:"x += 2; // equals 7; equivalent to x = x + 2;"

Comment: @Avamander if you'll notice the post was edited after my comment to include the answer to my second question, but thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the link. It has helped a lot.